# Attachments broken after giving WordPress its own directory

Tags: plugins, attachments, import

I set up a fresh WordPress installation in a folder called 'wp' under root. I followed the directions for [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) and pointed the URL to root successfully. I then proceeded to import some posts which had attachments to them. My uploads folder is currently set to /wp/wp-content/uploads but throughout the posts, the attachment URLs point to /wp-content/uploads.

I tried creating a symlink through the shell but that didn't work. Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since (from what I understand) the issue only occurs to imported posts I suggest you try the [plugin Search and Replace](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/). It's a quick and easy way to solve this problem.

WP stores the uploaded images in your database. Imported images probably direct to the old root, so you should change that to the new root. Search for the string `'/wp-content/uploads'` and replace all with `'/wp/wp-content/uploads'`. Be really careful with this plugin though, it's a powerful one.

Comment: Turns out most of the attachments had imported correctly but there were about 30 of them which hadn't. This plugin did the trick. It is very powerful indeed. Thank you so much for your help!